# Serverless Unable to import module 'handler' Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

When I'm testing on local machine it's working fine, but after I deploy it to lambda, it's not working anymore. It throws this error:

> Unable to import module 'handler': Error
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue. Please can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: are you exporting the `handler`? And can you post a bare minimum example? Without that it is hard to debug.

Comment: Also, double check if some dependencies are NOT in `devDependencies` which you are using. And all the packages that are being used are in `package.json`s `dependencies`.

Comment: which lambda version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the structure like:

```
  |--lambda
  |    `----create.js
  |--serverless.yml
```

Then try this.

### In file serverless.yml:

```
functions:
    create:
        handler: create.handle
```

### In file, lambda/create.js

```
module.exports.handle = async event => {
    return "something";
};
```

### check my example code at https://github.com/yogesh-sinoriya/serverless-dynamodb-authorizer